# Gnome graphical interface failed to load

Tags: debian, gnome, startx

I have Debian Linux with Gnome on my laptop.

My laptop dropped from a chair (It was off at that moment). I turned it on. It loads to text mode directly. I log in and run `startx`. It runs and mouse cursor comes on the screen. But display stays black and nothing happens.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Reinstall your xserver and desktop environment :

```
apt-get install aptitude tasksel
aptitude install xorg mesa-utils
tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```

2.You can check the xserver behavior and errors (Access permissions, drivers, ..etc) by configuring a logfile :

```
startx &> ~/.Xoutput
```